# Style Combobox AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox

I don't want to skin a ComboBox but I want to set its style with setStyle.

I found it can be used a syntax like the one below:

```
aCb.setStyle("textPadding", 10); 
aCb.setStyle("buttonWidth", 10);
```

What I want to do is the following:

- eliminate the default "divisions" between list items;
- change the rollover color;

Is this possible? How?

Comment: What ComboBox do you use (Flash, Flex 3, Flex 4)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's hard to answer without knowing what component you are applying the style to.

In Flex 4 for the s:ComboBox:

Rollover colour:

```
aCb.setStyle("rollOverColor", "#FF0000"); // changes the colour to bright red
```

Not sure what you mean by divisions.  There are various spacing properties including:

```
aCb.setStyle("paddingTop", 0);
aCb.setStyle("paddingBottom", 0);
aCb.setStyle("leading", 0);
```

Comment: When you don't style the component, between the items you can see a "border", I don't know how to name it (in a traditional HTML combobox you have no border).

Comment: Ok. That border sounds like the padding - space applied around the individual items.  By default it's 2 or 3 pixels.  There are two other padding properties paddingLeft and paddingRight.  The property [leading] holds the spacing between lines.  If you try the styling I suggested does it give you the desired effect?